# Save file in eclipse makes processor works hard

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse juno. Every time i save a file, eclipse consume 100% processor.

Here are the snapshot from top command :

```
Tasks: 303 total,   1 running, 301 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 31,2 us,  1,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 65,6 id,  0,4 wa,  0,0 hi,  1,4 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8077332 total,  5122068 used,  2955264 free,   509476 buffers
KiB Swap:  8252412 total,        0 used,  8252412 free,  2242736 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 3816 iwan      20   0 1141m 410m  35m S 100,9  5,2  59:00.47 eclipse           
 3882 iwan      20   0  594m 162m  52m S   2,3  2,1   6:09.30 skype             
 2646 iwan      20   0  309m  82m  32m S   2,0  1,0   9:05.18 compiz            
 3894 iwan      20   0  851m 171m  42m S   2,0  2,2   3:00.66 thunderbird       
 1305 root      20   0  266m  68m  55m S   1,3  0,9   7:55.87 Xorg
```

any ideas ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug with an application, which should be taken up with the creators of that application and doesn't have much to do with [so].

Comment: Suggest to use latest eclipse version unless you have specific reason to use old version. Also check whether lots of action set in `Save Actions` preference page. Go to `Windows->Preferences` then type `Save Actions` in top left search box.

Answer (score 0):

Apply any available updates. If problems continue, keep an eye on http://bugs.eclipse.org/402018 .